# How to cast imported data from CSV into Hive

Tags: csv, hive, hdfs

I am interested in importing a CSV file into a Hive table. The first field from the Hive table (ts) is of type BIGINT.  After performing the following query, Hive ams_csv table is successfully created but the ts values are NULL.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ams_csv (ts BIGINT, id STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION '/tmp/csvFilesDirectory';
```

I performed the same query but with the following modification and it worked:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ams_csv (ts STRING, id STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LOCATION '/tmp/csvFilesDirectory';
```

I am not interested in having ts of type String. Does anyone know how to perform the cast. I thought it was implicit.
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give a snippet of data which you are using, keeping in the csv file ? First 3-4 lines.

Comment: Here I have the solution :) In fact I didn't notice that my csv was wrong formatted causing the issue I had